# Создание объектов конструктора, желательно при помощи цикла for

Tags: java, объекты, for

Пусть есть конструктор Cat(String colour). Как создать определенное кол-во (пусть 20) объектов этого конструктора (с разными именами: cat1, cat2, ..., catN) и подать на вход случайные цвета? Остальное содержимое конструктора значения не имеет, там константы типа кол-ва лап. Желательно циклом for. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Может быть можно в конструкторе тоже сделать автоматически чтобы задавало рандомный цвет из массива заранее созданного в классе конструктора? Это корректно будет?

```
//Не судите строго, я только учусь, могу писать какие-нибудь глупости
```

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Я создаю массив с числами от 0 до 19 и пытаюсь плюсовать числа к имени, но java так не позволяет сделать, либо я неправильно пишу @MBo

Answer (score 3):

Перечисление цветов со статичным методом, который выдаёт случайный цвет:

```
public enum CatColor {
    BLACK, WHITE, GREY, RED, BLUE;

    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static int colorsCount = values().length;

    public static CatColor getRandomColor() {
        return values()[random.nextInt(colorsCount)];
    }
}
```

Класс кота:

```
public class Cat {
    private String name;
    private CatColor color;

    public Cat(String name, CatColor color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public CatColor getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cat " + name + " has color " + color;
    }
}
```

main метод:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
    //создаём котов
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Cat cat = new Cat("cat"+(i+1), CatColor.getRandomColor());
        cats.add(cat);
    }
    //печатаем котов
    cats.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Cat cat1 has color BLUE
Cat cat2 has color WHITE
Cat cat3 has color BLACK
Cat cat4 has color BLACK
Cat cat5 has color RED
Cat cat6 has color BLUE
Cat cat7 has color WHITE
Cat cat8 has color RED
Cat cat9 has color WHITE
Cat cat10 has color BLUE
Cat cat11 has color RED
Cat cat12 has color WHITE
Cat cat13 has color GREY
Cat cat14 has color WHITE
Cat cat15 has color BLACK
Cat cat16 has color GREY
Cat cat17 has color GREY
Cat cat18 has color BLACK
Cat cat19 has color BLUE
Cat cat20 has color BLACK
```

Answer (score 2):

Массив номеров не нужен - есть ведь счётчик цикла. А добавить его к строке - например, с помощью `Integer.ToString()`  (или `String.valueOf(number)`, или формировать сложную строку с помощью `String.format`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
       System.out.println("cat" + Integer.toString(i));
```

и даже работает (IMHO, нехорошо для типизированного языка)

```
 System.out.println("cat" + i);
```

По поводу цветов - полностью случайный выбор может привести к генерации очень похожих цветов. Если количество экземпляров ограничено, то разумно создать массив/список не очень близких цветов, и случайно выбирать из него (например, с помощью одной итерации тасования Фишера-Йетса)